# Import boost-generated python extension fails when outside libs/python/example

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost, boost-python

I am using an Ubuntu-based distro (Elementary OS Loki) and trying to create a running hello world python extension from a .cpp file, in a different directory than the one Boost is installed in. My Boost version is boost_1_63_0.

I am new to Boost. I managed to run the hello world example from the libs/python/example/tutorial Boost directory. I am calling bjam, it generates the .so and I am able to import the generated library in Python3.5.

When I copy the .cpp in a different directory outside Boost installation dir, it doesn't work in the same way. Building using bjam works fine, but when I try to import the generated module in python3.5 it gives an ImportError: `$PWD/hello_ext.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv`

This is the output when running bjam --debug-configuration:

```
notice: found boost-build.jam at /home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from /home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src
notice: Searching '/etc' '/home/bianca' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in '/etc' '/home/bianca' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/.'.
notice: Searching '/home/bianca' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/.' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from '/home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src'.
notice: will use 'g++' for gcc, condition <toolset>gcc-5.4
notice: using gcc libraries :: <toolset>gcc-5.4 :: /usr/bin /usr/lib /usr/lib32 /usr/lib64
notice: using gcc archiver :: <toolset>gcc-5.4 :: /usr/bin/ar
notice: using gcc ranlib :: <toolset>gcc-5.4 :: /usr/bin/ranlib
warning: toolset gcc initialization: can not find tool windres
warning: initialized from /home/bianca/Documents/programs/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/user-config.jam:45
notice: using rc compiler :: <toolset>gcc-5.4 :: /usr/bin/as
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "3.5"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified cmd-or-prefix: "/usr/bin/python3"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified includes: "/usr/include/python3.5"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified libraries: "/usr/lib"
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "/usr/bin/python3"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "/usr/include/python3.5"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "/usr/lib"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking for NumPy...
notice: [python-cfg] running command '/usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())"'
notice: [python-cfg] NumPy disabled. Reason:
notice: [python-cfg]   /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())" aborted with 
notice: [python-cfg]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
...found 10 targets...
```

In the current directory, I have the exact same .cpp file as in the libs/python/example/tutorial/ and a Jamroot which contains:

```
import python ;

if ! [ python.configured ]
{
  ECHO "warning: no Python configured in user-config.jam" ;
  ECHO "warning: will use default configuration" ;
  using python ;
}

# Adjust the following if Boost.Python isn't installed in a default
# location
lib boost_python ;

python-extension hello_ext : hello.cpp ;
```

My user-config.jam file is in tools/build/src and contains the gcc configuration `using gcc : 5.4 : g++ ;` and python configuration `using python : 3.5 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.5 : /usr/lib ;`

Any thoughts on why this fails?

Comment: what is the output of `ldd hello_ext.so`?

Comment: I'm getting `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd8efde000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb414352000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb41413c000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb413d72000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb413a69000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ff37d18000)`

Comment: Given you're getting an undefined symbol error, it suggests boost python is not on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, it looks as if you're not even linking boost_python, since it doesn't appear in the ldd output. Have you tried copying libboost_python.so into the same folder as your hello_ext.so?

Comment: Do you mean stage/lib/libboost_python.so ? Other posts suggested linking with boost python when simply compiling it with gcc, but I don't know how to do that from the Jamfile...

Comment: I tried copying that file in the same folder as hello_ext.so as you suggested and there was no change...

Comment: Have you installed boost after you built it? `b2 install` Did you specify an install prefix?

Comment: I believe I did that a while ago. Do you know how I can check?

Comment: `locate libboost_python.so`

Comment: I have it in /usr/local/lib, apart from boost_1_63_0/stage/lib and boost_1_63_0/bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/threading-multi `/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.63.0` so that means it is installed?

Comment: Yes it seems it is installed. Sorry, not really sure what to try next

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestions :)